# Cannot resolve symbol 'R'

Tags: java, android

De un momento a otro, todas mis Activity java me muestra error en el recurso R[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has intentado Build->Clean, Build->Rebuild?

Comment: Revisa tus layout por si alguno contiene un error.

Comment: Era eso Einer.
Porque reinicie el Android Studio y todavía seguir el problema.

Comment: Se soluciono entonces?

Comment: Si, se soluciono. Gracias.

Comment: Lo agregare como repuesta para que quede registrado.

Comment: Gracias por responder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has  `Build->Clean` y luego `Build->Rebuild` para que el IDE limpie cache y reconozca los nuevos cambios.

Answer (score 0):

Este problema ocurre a veces al añadir una dependencia -de biblioteca- de modo asistido, que no es correctamente efectuada.
Por ejemplo si has añadido la dependencia de una biblioteca con un nivel de versión, cuando se requiere otro nivel de version
En tal caso, prueba a ajustar la dependencia de modo manual:

1. accede al app/build.gradle
2. ajusta las dependencias (por ejemplo, corrige ciertos niveles de versión para que coincidan)
3. guarda y sincroniza (ves a Tools/Android/Sync projects with Gradle files)